# Making JSF buttons which act like "Backspace" and "Enter" Keys for an inputTextArea?

Tags: java, jsf-2

**UPDATE:** I updated here for clarity, instead of writing in the comments or making an answer post.

This is a piece of how the code those buttons will operate upon looks:

I made the buttons like this:

```
  <h:commandButton value="Delete"  onclick="return addBackspace();">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="formula"/>
                </h:commandButton> //the backspace button
```

The textArea:

```
 <h:inputTextarea id="formula" value="#{output.formula}" />
```

I made some simple buttons which would write their value to the textArea so the user sees the formula as he builds it:

```
 <h:commandButton value="+ "  onclick="return checkButtons(this.value);">                   
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="formula"/>
                </h:commandButton>
```

I'm not entirely sure about the ajax part i put in there, used it to stop the page refresh on every click.

And the selectBoxes I use which have some hardcoded values now but will eventually be filled with data taken from a WS.

```
 Property:
                <h:selectOneMenu  value ="#{output.propertyReferenceValue}" id="selectTwo" onchange="return checkItem(this.value);">    
                    <f:selectItems value="#{property.propertyReference.keySet()}"/> 
                </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Now if i make the textArea disabled or readOnly, I'm still able to write the content of the selctBoxes in it(which is good) but if i try the simple buttons like "+" their value will just appear quickly and then dissapear just as fast. If i try the backspace , it will delete the whole content of the textArea, same if i put some of the content of the selectboxes in the textArea and then if I click the "+" button (for example), the whole content of the area will be deleted. I'm still digging through the code to see what it is that makes it behave this way :)

**END OF UPDATE**

Would it be possible to make some commandButtons in JSF which will operate on an inputTextArea just like the "Enter" and "Backspace" keys? For example:

The "Enter Button" when pressed, will move the cursor to a new line of the textArea.
The "Backspace Button" will delete the next letter or space which is behind the cursor.

I've been searching for a while , but i seem to find only details on how to make all the text dissapear.

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Well I've managed to make the "Enter button" like this:      document.getElementById("texAreaId").value +="\n"; . Still trying to work out the "Backspace button"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use JavaScript for this.

E.g.

```html
<h:inputTextarea id="textarea" binding="#{textarea}" value="#{bean.text}" />
<input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="addEnter('#{textarea.clientId}')" />
<input type="button" value="Backspace" onclick="addBackspace('#{textarea.clientId}')" />
```

with those functions

```js
function addEnter(textareaId) {
    var textarea = document.getElementById(textareaId);
    textarea.value += '\n';
    textarea.focus();
}

function addBackspace(textareaId) {
    var textarea = document.getElementById(textareaId);
    textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0, textarea.value.length - 1);
    textarea.focus();
}
```

Comment: A related question: If i make the textArea "disabled" the addBackspace will delete its whole content. Is it possible to modify the addBackspace to still delete according to the cursor position(not sure about this one , since the textArea is disabled the cursor goes with it as far as i can tell) or to make it delete the last word?

Comment: Interesting, I can't reproduce your issue on FF6, IE7/8/9 and GC13. What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome.

Comment: I upgraded to GC14, but I still can't reproduce it. Perhaps there's more into your code which is conflicting with this?

Comment: unfortunately I can't check that right now, but I will do it in the morning and update this right after.

Comment: Oh, you're submitting the form to the server. I didn't expect that. I expected it to take place entirely client side like as shown in my answer. You cannot submit a disabled or readonly value to the server. You'd have to copy it to a hidden input field.

Comment: Oh wow, I actually managed to do that without realising. I guess I'm doing that through the <h:commandButton> ?. Yes you are right, the whole thing should happen on the client side(just some data will be taken from the server at some point to fill the selectBoxes). Thanks again for the input :)